# jQuery: each function iteration for a table selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

`$(".TableContainer.MyTable table")` this selector gives me an array of 3 tables. I do highlighting for my tables first 15 table data rows. I want to do this for all tables within the jQuery selector array.

`$('#MyTable tbody tr td').slice(0, 15).addClass("highlight");` is what I use to add class `highlight` to the first 15 table datas for a single table. How do I use this selector for each table in first selector?

How do I achieve this using `.each()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really don't even need `each` as there are enough selectors and methods available to do what you need in one chain:

```
$(".TableContainer.MyTable table").find('tr:lt(16) td').addClass("highlight");
```

The way this works is the initial collection is the 3 tables and internally jQuery will loop over all 3 (using `each` within jQuery core) and perform the methods that follow

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/9ou9dnoL/)**</kbd>